# MacBook Pro showing weird screen on reboot and trackpad not workong

Tags: macbook-pro

[image]

My MacBook Pro 2017 version is showing this screen for some reason. And my trackpad is not working.I have no idea what to do.
Any help would me much appreciated

Comment: It looks like a "Please switch this on" advisory - I've never owned a Macbook,  but the picture presumably matches one side of it & there's a switch...

Comment: The picture looks like the back of an external trackpad. It sounds like there's a hardware error if the Macbook doesn't recognise that there's an internal trackpad.